# Handling server failure in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using a configuration of socket io, redis as a cache, rabbitMQ for pub  sub and mongo DB as a secondary store for a chat application. Basically, redis is used as a store to set the connected user status as online or offline, user conversation ids, participants and a couple of more data points. In  my use case there could be multiple users connected with the same user id but multiple socket connections, so I am keeping  a counter on the user as a hash on redis and incrementing it every time a user is connected with the same id on connection.

In the

`socket.on('disconnect')`

event I am writing the decrement counter logic where if the number of sockets connected with the same userID is 4 then  it is set to 3  and if it is 1 its set to 0 and the user is set to offline. The problem is, if my server stops , the on disconnect event is not triggered and the next time when the server comes up a new connection is made and the counter is incremented so for example it there were 3 sockets connected then it will  make it 4 . I plan to solve it by keeping a set of all the connected users in a set on redis and when the server goes down I am writing some cleanup code in

`process.on('exit')`

Where it will read the set of all the connected users from the redis  set and set them to offline and count to 0. So that when the server comes back up all the clients can start incrementing the count.

**The Problem** -
I plan to deploy it on amazon elastic beanstalk, so when it scales out on traffic I will  have to maintain a machine specific set of users connected so that when the node goes down it will only set the status of the user  that were connected to that node to offline and the count to 0.

FYI - I have written a fallback mechanism where if it does not find the data  points on redis it will query mongoDB and set it on redis. So, when the server goes down, I could just clear redis and let it repopulate on its own. But I do not want to clear redis as its inefficient to repopulate at scale and in the long run.

Thank  you so much for your  time.

Answer (score 0):

First off, how often is your server going down? This should be an edge-case. That said, I would have a unique id for each connection, then keep track of which users have which connections.

For the sharing-state-through-redis part... how is redis set up? Does an instance of it spin up on each ec2 instance as part of the EB app? Or are you using something like ElastiCache? If the former, you don't have to worry, since each server has its own redis instance. If the later, you could have each server register itself when it comes online - it could add an entry to a list. Then it should get a unique ID back, and it can use that as a prefix, so you can identify which users and connections are tied to a given server.

Comment: Thank  for taking the time out to answer this question. I have not faced any downtime yet but I need to make a robust system. 

I am using ElasticCache as it is shared by all the instances. As the online offline status of the user is set on redis a third user would want to know if a user is online or offline connected to a different instance. 
The thing is, I could get the the instance id and maintain a list of connected users to the instance as a list on redis.

Comment: But then on disconnection I would have to pull out the  user from the list, which would take  O(n) for every disconnection, wouldn't that be too much?

Comment: Sorry I assumed some things. Did you know that socket.io had built in logic so clients reconnect with the server after a disconnect? https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: Have you tested just letting the client attempt to reconnect?

Comment: Also, are you using socket.io-redis? Using it would hide that there are multiple node servers, and let you write logic as if there’s just one socket.io process. Between that and the default reconnecting behavior, as long as you are using forever or pm2 or something to quickly restart on crash, it seems like you shouldn’t need to purge a bunch of connections.

Comment: Hi Sam  i think you got my problem right I will explain in a little more detail so that you undersatnd it completely. So the thing is this is a chat application, and one  user can log in from multiple device, so I am setting the status of user as online when the user comes online and I am keeping a count of the number of users connected with the same id so it goes like.

Comment: `socket.on('connected', function() {
// if a user with the same id was already connected

   // increment the count

  // else  
   // set the count to 1 and set status to online
   socket.on( 'disconnect', function(){ 
            // if count of the users connected is 1
            // set count to 0 and status to offline
           // else 
           // just decrement the count 
    })`

Comment: So now you can see if the disconnect event is not fired the online count of the user is never decremented and the user stays online forever. As you said I am thinking to maintain a list of users connected to each instance so that if  an instance goes down i will fire a lambda function  which will decrement the online user count connected to that instance. The only problem in maintaining this list is on every disconnected I will have to pull out this user id from the list which will take O(n) but I  dont think thats a lot, I will maintain the list  on redis. Thank you for your kind replies.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. Thanks for the additional detail (you may want to add that to the original post). I think you are re-implementing functionality that is already built into socket.io. Assume a server goes down, but you’ve been tracking client connections (IDs, not just count). When the server comes back online, it will try to reconnect with all clients. Why not just have some logic to remove whichever connections it can’t reconnect with?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sam, I will look into this. Will post a solution as soon as I find one.